# Make a div overlap another

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Hi so I am using foundation to create a navigation bar and would like to achieve the effect seen in the photo where the logo box overlaps the content below it however currently it is expanding the height of the whole navigation bar and not just the logo section.

What I would like it to look like:
[image]
What it is looks now: 
[image]

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="logo large-3 columns">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-text"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



<div class="large-9 columns">
  <div class="large-12 infobar ">


    <div class="hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only row">
    <div class="large-3 info_numbers columns grey info_padding">
      20°C
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns info_numbers info_padding  no-padding grey "> <i class="fa fa-phone icon-padding"></i>018803 294110</div>
    <div class="large-4 columns smaller-font info_padding grey no-padding"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o icon-padding"></i>STAY@GROSVENORHOUSEHOTEL.CO.UK</div>
    <div class="large-3 columns no-padding text-right">
    <a href="#" class="main-button small book_button">check availability</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row  ">

    <div class="large-12 header_info">
      <header class="no-padding top-bar-item " role="banner">
         <!-- This navs will be applied to the topbar, above all content
            To see additional nav styles, visit the /parts directory -->
         <?php get_template_part( 'parts/nav', 'topbar' ); ?>
      </header> <!-- end .header -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
    background-color: $secondary-color;
    min-height:10em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to re-create your menu in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? We'll need to see all of the css you're using for the navigation bar in order to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Give .logo a position of `absolute` instead of `relative`, and give it an explicit height and width.

Comment: I will be placing a logo in there so there will be no need for the min-height I just placed it in to show the problem I am having where the div explands the div it is within instead overlapping the one below and that expanding the one it is within

Comment: See my edit. It is my best guess, since your html and css have variables and code snippets in them from other languages, which makes it very difficult to see what the exact problem is. Ig you revise the code, and just include the html markup that is causing the problem, it might be easier to help you.